# Android Studio Attribute Confusion

Tags: android-studio

In the android studio software, my attribute table for XML code keeps going back to floating mode, no matter how many times I change it. When I try to stick it back in the table, it comes back in floating mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the gear --> Attatched Side set you want...

Comment: i even tried attached side to right, but not working